# how to append data to df index with two list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have this

```py
list1 = [35,85]
list2= [58741,6352]
```

where the list1 is the index of one df and list2 is the value in that index

i use this code

```
for i in list1:
   for h in list2:
    df.loc[i, 'column name'] = h
```

but i only get the last value in the list2 for every index in list 1

i want to get this

| index | column name |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | 58741 |
| 85 | 6352 |

thanks!

Comment: Whats wrong with `pd.DataFrame({'col_name': list2}, index=list1)`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris it doesn't work because df is not a new dataframe, i want to insert it to one df i already created

Comment: append the two frames together

Comment: Can you show us the dataframe you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with this code:

```
for list1,list2 zip(list1,list2):
    df.loc[list1,'column name'*] = list2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.loc`:

```py
list1 = [35, 85]
list2 = [58741, 6352]

df.loc[list1, "column name"] = list2
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       column name
index             
20             999
35           58741
40             999
85            6352
60             999
```

---

`df` used:

```
       column name
index             
20             999
35             999
40             999
85             999
60             999
```